# In Django, how can I allow 'null' values in a field programatically from the form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am actually programing an application in django and I have the next model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    att1= models.ForeignKey(B, related_name="att1")
    att2= models.ForeignKey(C)
    ...
```

As you can see, the attributes of the model cannot be 'null'.

I also have a search-form of the model above, and, when I treat it in the correspondent view, I have the next error in this code line:

```
        # If the two forms are valid...
    if A_form.is_valid():
```

Error -> Cannot assign None: "A.att1" does not allow null values.

So that I supose the error occurs because in the model I didn´t define null=True for that attribute.

Well, the problem is that when I create an object referenced to de model A, I want the attributes 'att1' and 'att2' not to be 'null', but in the search form it doesn't matter if the fields are filled. Of course, in the form, I defined that the attributes are not required with required=False:

```
class Aform(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Aform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Making name required
    self.fields['att1'].required = False
    self.fields['att2'].required = False
```

So, my question is: how can I fix this error? Can I attach "null=True" option to the attributes in the form, as well as I could do in the model definition? Is there any way to allow the attributes be null in the search form?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Just to be clear, where is the form `A_form`? Is it a modelform of `A`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Aform` is not overriding directly `forms.ModelForm`, you can override `is_valid` or `clean_att1`

Doc of `clean_att1` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)